# Get dummy variables from a string column full of mess

Tags: python, regex, pandas, dummy-variable

I'm a less-than-a-week beginner in Python and Data sciences, so please forgive me if these questions seem obvious.

I've scraped data on a website, but the result is unfortunately not very well formatted and I can't use it without transformation.

**My Data**

I have a string column which contains a lot of features that I would like to convert into dummy variables.

**Example of string** : "8 équipements & optionsextérieur et châssisjantes aluintérieurBluetoothfermeture électrique5 placessécuritékit téléphone main libre bluetoothABSautreAPPUI TETE ARclimatisation"

**What I would like to do**

I would like to create a dummy colum "Bluetooth" which would be equal to one if the pattern "bluetooth" is contained in the string, and zero if not.

I would like to create an other dummy column "Climatisation" which would be equal to one if the pattern "climatisation" is contained in the string, and zero if not.

...etc

And do it for 5 or 6 patterns which interest me.

**What I have tried**

I wanted to use a match-test with regular expressions and to combine it with pd.getdummies method.

```
import re
import pandas as pd

def match(My_pattern,My_strng):
    m=re.search(My_pattern,My_strng)
    if m:
        return True
    else:
        return False

pd.getdummies(df["My messy strings colum"], ...)
```

I haven't succeeded in finding how to settle pd.getdummies arguments to specify the test I would like to apply on the column.

I was even wondering if it's the best strategy and if it wouldn't be easier to create other parallels columns and apply a match.group() on my messy strings to populate them.
Not sure I would know how to program that anyway.

Thanks for your help

Comment: you can use `df['bluetooth'] = df['column'].str.contains('Bluetooth').astype(int)`

Comment: Thank you very much, it worked after having filled with anything all the NaN elements.

Answer (score 0):

I think one way to do this would be:

```
df.loc[df['My messy strings colum'].str.contains("bluetooth", na=False),'Bluetooth'] = 1
df.loc[~(df['My messy strings colum'].str.contains("bluetooth", na=False)),'Bluetooth'] = 0

df.loc[df['My messy strings colum'].str.contains("climatisation", na=False),'Climatisation'] = 1
df.loc[~(df['My messy strings colum'].str.contains("climatisation", na=False)),'Climatisation'] = 0
```

The tilde (~) represents *not*, so the condition is reversed in this case to string *does not contain*.

na = false means that if your messy column contains any null values, these will not cause an error, they will just be assumed to not meet the condition.

Comment: Thank you, it works as well and raised my attention on the NaN issue.

Comment: Sure, but apologies, I don't know how to do. Where can I do this ?

Comment: You'll see next to my answer there is a little grey tick, which once clicked goes green